# Identification of Bluetooth IC marked TED8402818

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Today I opened [a Bluetooth headset](https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-1109469/%D9%87%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%B2%D9%81%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%AB-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-hcwy-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81-001) (from **HCWY** company) and saw this circuit:

[image: photo of PCB inside Bluetooth headset 1]

[image: photo of PCB inside Bluetooth headset 1]

So I try to read the IC number on it and found something like **TED8402818**, but didn't found anything using Google. Also there is one steel coated IC and I cannot read its number. It seems simple and only has two ICs with Rx, Tx pins which I think is for programming it.

So I would like to know about the circuit and those ICs.

Comment: Whats the make & model of the headset itself?

Comment: It'll be a custom chip requiring a lot of effort (and NDAs) to get close to the internals. Are you that bothered to know?

Comment: I added the detail about marks, aldo i am not bothered man but like to know, so asked here.

Comment: @so - The "steel coated IC" is a crystal or crystal oscillator, not an IC. The photo quality is not enough to read its marking (which will give a clue to its frequency). FYI that information from the crystal / oscillator will not help you to identify the main IC.